# I want to show leftdays in messagebox in below code ... there is no error ..but its no showing the messagebox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

i m trying to show the remainingdays in the code below plus also want to show as count days and save it in Database .. like everyday remaining days should appears to be changed

```
//i want to get the two dates which is already saved in sql and then 
//calculating the remaining days
//reading the data 
using (SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
    //loop throught the reader
    while (read.Read()) {
        // putting the salarydate value from database to first variable 
        String first =(read["salarydate"].ToString());
        // putting the expirydate value from database to second variable
        String Second = (read["expiredate"].ToString());

        //converting the first fron string to datetime and then saving it to another 
        //datetime variable name salaryDate
        DateTime salaryDate = DateTime.ParseExact(first, "MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        //converting the second fron string to datetime and then saving it to another 
        //datetime variable name expireDate
        DateTime expireDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Second, "MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        //timepaning between two 
        TimeSpan t1 = expireDate - salaryDate;

        //storing the days from t1 to daysleft which means days remaining 
        int daysleft = t1.Days; //days left 

        //this message box is not showing
        //i also want to save the difference  in sql and when that difference become 
        //zero , i want to put condition on that ..
        MessageBox.Show(daysleft.ToString(),"Days Left");
    }
}
```

Comment: And which is the problem you have with your code?

Comment: Over Here  :

Error is : 
String is not Valid DateTime.

Comment: Well, what does the string look like?  Debug it.

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong with the format of your strings "first" and "second"  Debug what you get out from the database, if you get anything, and arrange the correct formatting.

Most probably from the DB you get a string that is "dd/MM/yyyy" and than you try to format that string in "MM/dd/yyyy", but it depends on the language settings.

To test my answer I have replaced the output from the DB with typed strings and your code is working without errors.